# How to set default value for fields added to user profile using ACF

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, user-roles, user-meta

I am adding several fields to the user profiles using ACF, example field setup with location set as user profile:

```
...
array(
    'key'          => 'field_user_created_id',
    'label'        => 'User ID',
    'name'         => 'user_created_id',
    'type'         => 'text',
    'instructions' => 'Generated user ID.',
    'readonly'     => 1,
),
....
'location' => array(
        array(
            array(
                'param'    => 'user_form',
                'operator' => '==',
                'value'    => 'all',
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

I want to set the `user_created_id` field value to the generated user ID. Is there a way I can set the default value of these fields?